# How to prevent list items from overlapping in an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css, list

I have a div and inside that div are list items. Each list item needs to go below the other, so the default of the list property. However, the div surrounding it **needs** to be positioned absolutely to prevent re-sizing of the div it is in, and for the design to work. However, each list item overlaps when the parent div is positioned absolutely. Positioning the list items as relative does not resolve the issue.

HTML:

```
{block:Pagination}
<div class="pagination">
{block:PreviousPage}
    <a href="{PreviousPage}"><img id="pagination"    
src="http://static.tumblr.com/txc9jrr/JlWmd5ncd/previouspage.png"></a>
    {/block:PreviousPage}

{block:JumpPagination length="5"}
<ol class="jumpPage">
            {block:JumpPage}
            <li class="jumpPageNumber">
                <a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
            </li>
            {/block:JumpPage}
</ol>
{/block:JumpPagination}

{block:NextPage}
    <a href="{NextPage}"><img id="pagination" 
src="http://static.tumblr.com/txc9jrr/9Wtmd5mxb/nextpage.png"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
```

CSS:

```
.pagination {
display:inline-block;
}

#pagination {
width:28px;
height:28px;
margin:0 0 -6px 0;
}

ol.jumpPage {
position:absolute;
}

.jumpPageNumber {
list-style:none;
}

a.jump_page {
color:#ababab;
background:#FF0000;
}
```

The list elements are generated by Tumblr's server, not me.

Comment: Bad markup first give LI inside UL or OL

Comment: I tried with the same results.

Comment: Can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net for better understanding

Comment: In normal context, it functions properly. However, I'm making a page at earlcoding.tumblr.com and on the bottom right you can see the "5". Under that "5" are the other list elements, however because the parent ol is set to position:absolute; they overlap. I'm perplexed as to what's causing this.

Comment: It would be more feasible if you could provide a better code snippet with all the parent elements (with CSS & JS code, if any) in place. Also, separate the HTML, CSS and JS code in your post for better readability and understanding. Moreover, if you could create an example on some site like jsfiddle.net, like sandeep suggested, it would ease things for others.

Comment: I will add the parent elements and the css, however I am avoiding jsfiddle because I am curious if it has to do with Tumblr's rendering of the elements (which I cannot produce with jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute & write like this:

**CSS**

```
#navigation > *{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ol class="jumpPage">
 <li class="jumpPageNumber">
  <a href="/page/2" class="jump_page">2</a>
 </li>
 <li class="jumpPageNumber">
  <a href="/page/3" class="jump_page">3</a>
 </li>
 <li class="jumpPageNumber">
  <a href="/page/4" class="jump_page">4</a>
 </li>
 <li class="jumpPageNumber">
  <a href="/page/5" class="jump_page">5</a>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This did not work. While they no longer overlap (due to the removal of absolute positioning) they still effect the other elements within their parent div(s).

Comment: can you give a snap how to want

Comment: earlcoding.tumblr.com The list on the bottom right should be outside of the bottom bar, not effecting the other elements. Also, thanks for helping! :-) Much appreciated.